# How do I sort the dynamic list in c#

Tags: c#, list, sorting, dynamic

```
function void sortDynamicData(typeOfClass,SortKey)
{
List<dynamic> results = null; //results might be of any type it may contain students data or books data or professors data, hence I took as dynamic
results = services.GetMyresults(typeOfClass); //returns list of dynamic objects

results = results.OrderBy(SortKey).ToList();
 ...
 ...
 ...

}
```

my question is I want to sort the results based on sortKey
Any help would be greatly appreciable.

Comment: without knowing a proper Key in `list.OrderBy(o=>o.Key).ToList()`, the sorting is not possible. Its better to sort in the method `services.GetMyresults(typeOfClass)` and send.

Comment: do you know the column name to sort by?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If possible, I think it's better and easier to work with if your data is List of T instead of List of dynamic

In case you cannot change your input data to List:

```
public List<dynamic> Sort<T>(List<dynamic> input, string property)
{
    var type = typeof(T);   
    var sortProperty = type.GetProperty(property);
    return input.OrderBy(p => sortProperty.GetValue(p, null)).ToList();
}
```

Usage: you need to provide the type of data in the list, e.g. sort List by Name property in which dynamic is of Person type

```
var result = Sort<Person>(people, "Name");
```

================

**Update:**

In case you cannot provide the type of data, you can try this Sort()

```
public List<dynamic> Sort(List<dynamic> input, string property)
{   
    return input.OrderBy(p => p.GetType()
                               .GetProperty(property)
                               .GetValue(p, null)).ToList();
}
```

Usage:

```
var people = new List<dynamic>
{
    new Person { Name = "Person 5" },
    new Person { Name = "Person 2" },
    new Person { Name = "Person 9" },
    new Person { Name = "Person 1" }
};  

var result = Sort(people, "Name");
```

Comment: Nice. starred this :D

Comment: But I have 100's of types, I am giving a provision to user to create their own class, I need to sort the data
sample data is List<dynamic> results = new List<dynamic>(); 
            for(int i=0;i<15;i++)
            {
                dynamic obj = new ExpandoObject();
                obj.Name = i.ToString();
                obj.Id = i;
                obj.Total = 14 - i;
                obj.Grade = (14 - i).ToString();
                results.Add(obj);
               
            }
            results = results.AsQueryable().OrderBy("Id").ToList();

Comment: I updated the method so that it doesn't need type of data, please take a look to see whether it's what you need

Comment: >_< This will have horrendous performance, tight looping on reflection...Its better create a `Func<dynamic, object>` to sort with. I personally like to do that with Linq Expressions.

Comment: yes, I agree that it might have potential performance impact in large list. But if the list is just 15 items like in the comment, I think user will hardly recognize any performance impact. Can you also post your solution on using Func<dynamic, object>?

Answer (score 2):

```
var final = results.AsEnumerable().OrderBy(x => x[0])
```

Comment: But the thing is I don't have any predefined structure for the list, that is of type dynamic,

Comment: Yup that's why I added the second syntax, You just need a way to determine index column  of your dynamic list. Meaning you don't have to do this. typeOfClass,SortKey --> the calling client must define this already

Comment: For dynamic list I should not use lambda expressions, I tries this but not working
results = results.AsQueryable().OrderBy(SortKey).ToList();

Comment: Can you post that so we can see what you are trying to do?

Comment: `list = list.AsEnumerable().OrderByDescending(x => x.SomeDynamicProperty).ToList<dynamic>();`

Answer (score 1):

**1- order by one field**

```
var personList = new List<dynamic>
{
    new { FullName = "Person 2" },
    new { FullName = "People 2" },
    new { FullName = "People 1" },
    new { FullName = "Person 1" }
};
    
List<dynamic> sortedPersonList = personList.AsEnumerable().OrderBy(x => x.FullName).ToList();
```

**result**

```
{ FullName = "People 1" }
{ FullName = "People 2" }
{ FullName = "Person 1" }
{ FullName = "Person 2" }
```

**2- order by multiple fields**

```
var personList = new List<dynamic>
{
     new { FirstName = "Person", LastName = "2" },
     new { FirstName = "People", LastName = "2" },
     new { FirstName = "People", LastName = "1" },
     new { FirstName = "Person", LastName = "1" }
};
        
List<dynamic> sortedPersonList = personList.AsEnumerable().OrderBy(x => x.FirstName).ThenBy(x => x.LastName).ToList();
```

**result**

```
{ FirstName = "People", LastName = "1" }
{ FirstName = "People", LastName = "2" }
{ FirstName = "Person", LastName = "1" }
{ FirstName = "Person", LastName = "2" }
```