# I need to sort a list of objects by unknown number of fields

Tags: c#, algorithm, linq, sorting

I can sort List by `LINQ`, if I know numbers of fields. But how can I make it universal for unknown numbers of fields?

```
var destObjectsCurrent = destObjects.OrderByDescending(x => 
x.PropValues["GroupingLevel1"].PropertyValue.ToString()).ThenByDescending(x => 
x.PropValues["GroupingLevel2"].PropertyValue.ToString()).ToList();
```

Comment: You want to sort by **all** fields within a dataset? Sounds a bit weird. Anyway: just use the first element in your list and get its properties using reflection.

Comment: Search dynamic LINQ SQL and build your order by based on each field having a value.

Comment: i want to sort it by all fields with the name "GroupingLevel{1...n}". What do you mean "using reflection"? can you show an example?

Comment: foreach (var prop in obj.GetType().GetProperties()) { var name = prop.Name; } Make a web search for 'get properties of class c# reflection' or similar to get more details

Comment: This should help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27683904/how-do-i-sort-the-dynamic-list-in-c-sharp